# css / attachment

Tags: css

Estou com um problema.
Quando eu uso qualquer outro attachment a imagem fica normal: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando eu uso o fixed para acompanhar o scroll ela da um zoom absurdo: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800');
/* CSS Document */
body { 
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    margin: 0; }
.background
{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/fundo.png);
    background-position: top center;
    min-height:355px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    color: #000000;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;

}

.background .links ul {
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;

}

.background .links ul li {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
}

.background .links ul li a {

    display: block;
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#ffffff;
}

.background .links ul li a:hover {
    color: #b0fafd;

}
```

Comment: Quais as dimensões da imagem de fundo? Acho que o problema não esteja no fixed.

Comment: Opa   essas são as dimensões.                                                                                            
  width: 1800px;
height: 358px;

Comment: essa é imagem de fundo do top do site e não a imagem de fundo do body .

Comment: Tente usar `auto` em vez de `cover`

Comment: Mt obrigado funcionou, como posso te elogiar por aqui?

Comment: Vou colocar uma resposta

Comment: Tranquilo mano só por q eu voto .

Answer (score 1):

O problema não está ligado ao `background-attachment`. O tamanho do `background` é definido em `background-size`. Usando `cover`, a imagem de fundo irá ocupar toda a largura e altura da `div` (como o próprio nome significa: *cobrir*) e a imagem poderá sofrer um aumento para isso, pois o `cover` manterá as dimensões (caso seja maior do que a `div)` e a proporção da imagem.

O que se deve fazer é ajustar o `background-size` em `100%`. O `100%` irá ajustar a largura da imagem de fundo de acordo com a largura da `div` mantendo a proporção da mesma.

[Mais info sobre background-size no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Comment: prontinho mano votei nas 2 .

Comment: @GabrielCosta Obrigado! Mas o interessante é marcar ✓